# File not found exception even after bufferedwriter close

Tags: java, io, struts2

New edit:
Now i found the cause, it is because there are two servers and it write into temp folder in 1st server and try to read from the 2nd one. But I still didn't find a solution for this unless write to Amazon S3 and read from there.

I tried to export csv with struts2 action. However if I tried to export 10 times i can only succeed once, all the others failed with File not found exception (if I refresh the link again, the file can be downloaded). Here is my code:

```
public String exportFile(String fileName) {
    File exportFile = null;
    try {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(receipts)) {
            return "";
        }

        exportFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".csv");
        exportFile.deleteOnExit();
        try (BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(exportFile))) {
            try {
                fw.write("test");
            } finally {
                fw.close();
            }
        }
        return exportFile.getPath();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Error exporting report. ", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}

String getStreamFromPath(String filePath) {
    try {
        File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

This is really weird, when i test in another server it works totally fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your file being created?

Comment: yes, when i check the tom-cat temp folder i can see the files, and if i refresh the link "downloadReceipt.action?receiptsFilePath=xxxx ", the file can be downloaded.

Comment: Is it due to this statement `exportFile.deleteOnExit();`? The 1st time always succeed and 2nd time onward throws exception.

Comment: hmm, it always fail the 1st time but if i refresh the link 2nd time it will succeed. Also deleteOnExit() will only delete the file when the JVM stopped normally.

Comment: deleteOnExit() seems to be a culprit here